# Filter the My Task list based on loggedin User in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a list called "My Task". In here we can assign task to particular user by HRUser.
Once that perticular user logged in the My task list the list should be showed only that particular user's Task.So dont allow him to see other's Task history in that list. How can I do it.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the (default) view on the list you can define filter on current user.
Go to the view settings and in the filter section:

- select the field containing the user
- as filter value set [me]

[me] is a buildin SharePoint token that will be replaced with the current username.

Keep in mind this is a filter, it does not enforce security . If a users plays a bit with the URL he can see other tasks as well.